# Configure number of RADIUS retransmits or timeout for Strongswan eap-radius

Tags: vpn, strongswan, radius

I have the following connection scheme:

```
Site A (radius server) <--> Site B (gateway) <--> Roadwarrior (Bob)
```

Site B uses eap-radius plugin for RADIUS Authentication and Accounting.

```
            eap-radius {
              dae {
                  enable = yes
                  listen = 0.0.0.0
                  port = 3799
                  secret = verystrongsecret
              }
              class_group = yes
              eap_start = no
              load = yes
              accounting = yes
              servers {
                server-a {
                  address = xx.xx.xx.xx
                  auth_port = 1812
                  acct_port = 1813
                  secret = verystrongsecret
                  nas_identifier = gw
                  sockets = 5
                }
              }
            }
```

Trap policies between Site A and Site B are configured.

```
children {
  net-net {
    local_ts = xx.xx.xx.xx/xx
    remote_ts = xx.xx.xx.xx/xx

    start_action = trap|start
    ...
  }
}
```

I then forcibly terminate a connection between radius server and gateway: `swanctl -t -i radius`

When Bob connects to gateway, RADIUS Auth fails before connection between radius server and gateway is established. Looks like IKE_SA with radius server wasn't initiated until EAP_RADIUS failed.

```
Nov 03 05:41:43 gw: received EAP identity 'user'
Nov 03 05:41:43 gw: sending RADIUS Access-Request to server 'server-a'
Nov 03 05:41:43 gw: creating acquire job for policy xx.xx.xx.xx/xx[udp/52470] === xx.xx.xx.xx/xx[udp/radius] with reqid {1}
Nov 03 05:41:44 gw: ignoring request with ID 2, already processing
Nov 03 05:41:45 gw: retransmit 1 of RADIUS Access-Request (timeout: 2.8s)
Nov 03 05:41:46 gw: ignoring request with ID 2, already processing
Nov 03 05:41:47 gw: retransmit 2 of RADIUS Access-Request (timeout: 3.9s)
Nov 03 05:41:50 gw: ignoring request with ID 2, already processing
Nov 03 05:41:51 gw: retransmit 3 of RADIUS Access-Request (timeout: 5.5s)
Nov 03 05:41:57 gw: RADIUS Access-Request timed out after 4 attempts
Nov 03 05:41:57 gw: initiating EAP_RADIUS method failed
Nov 03 05:41:57 gw: generating IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/FAIL ]
Nov 03 05:41:57 gw: sending packet: from xx.xx.xx.xx[4500] to xx.xx.xx.xx[23811] (80 bytes)
Nov 03 05:41:57 gw: initiating IKE_SA radius[31] to xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Bob connects successfully for the second time though since connection between Site A and Site B has already been established after the first connection try.

How can I overcome this problem to make sure site-to-site tunnel is up when clients connects to the gateway? Is it possible to increase RADIUS Authentication timeout (if it helps at all)?

Comment: Yes, you can change the number of retransmits and the interval (see [the docs](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/config/strongswanConf.html#_charon_plugins_eap_radius)). But four RADIUS messages are already sent during about 10 seconds. So why does it take so long to establish the connection between site A and site B? Actually, in the log there is an acquire for RADIUS traffic, but nothing seems to happen. Is there more to this log (i.e. did you omit messages)?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise there is a separate section in strongswan.conf docs devoted specifically to eap-radius (was looking for it on eap-radius plugin page). I did not omit messages in the log, under normal conditions (on daemon startup or manual start) connection is quick. Just tried to increase timeout / number of retransmits, and connection from site A to site B only happens after full RADIUS timeout (tried 60 seconds).

Comment: Tried to increase `sockets` in charon.plugins.eap-radius.servers.server and `events_buffer_size` in  charon.plugins.kernel-pfkey with no luck, it seems like eap-radius is working synchronously and locking connection.

Comment: Ah, this happens because the IKE_SA is locked while waiting for the RADIUS response. This will prevent the acquire to get handled as the code tries to find an existing IKE_SA to reuse. You can try disabling the `charon.reuse_ikesa` option to avoid this lookup.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, i'll monitor how this option affects performance